Python code to transmit data to a machine that uses a telnet service/terminal
I need to send the data in a CSV file (Data.csv) to a different machine that will receive it with a terminal using a telnet connection (Tera, Putty, HyperTerm, etc.). My code running at the source of the data is supposed to send each row every second to the port 2001 once it has successfully connected to the target machine, however, for a reason I have not been able to figure out I cannot connect to the target machine. My code waits 5 second between attempts to connect again (this is where I'm stuck) and transmission can be stopped by pressing enter.
The machine with the data has the static IP address 192.168.1.2 and DNS 255.255.255.0. The machine that receives the data has the static IP address 192.168.1.XX (XX not being 2) and same DNS.
I have tried different versions of the code below with the same result. I cannot stablish connection with the destination of the data. The following error message appears: ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
If anyone can shade some light on what I'm doing wrong, it'll be appreciated.
import csv
import socket
import time

def transmit_data(file_path, TrFreq, TrPort, TrDelimiter, TrLoop):
    while True:
        try:
            with open(file_path, 'r') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=TrDelimiter)
                with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                    s.settimeout(5)  # Set a timeout for connection attempts
                    s.connect(('localhost', TrPort))
                    print("Connection established. Starting transmission...")
                    for row in reader:
                        try:
                            data = TrDelimiter.join(row)
                            s.sendall(data.encode())
                            time.sleep(TrFreq)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print("Error:", e)
                        if input("Press Enter to stop transmission (or 'loop' to loop): ").strip() == '':
                            return
                    if not TrLoop:
                        return
        except socket.error as e:
            print("Connection failed. Retrying in 5 seconds...")
            time.sleep(5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Transmission aborted by user.")
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = "Data.csv"  # CSV file path
    TrFreq = 1  # Transmission frequency in seconds
    TrPort = 2001  # Transmission port
    TrDelimiter = ' '  # Delimiter for CSV data
    TrLoop = False  # Set to True to loop through the CSV file continuously, False to transmit once

    transmit_data(file_path, TrFreq, TrPort, TrDelimiter, TrLoop)

I also tried the telnetlib but I keep getting a message warning me that library will be retired soon, so I'm using socket connections instead. I also used the DataStreamer thing in excel and I'm able to transmit the data with no issues, but that solution requires someone to import the data to excel.

connect to the 192.168.1.xx address of the machine to receive the data, not localhost.  Also if it is a telnet machine, you need to send a newline-terminated string.  row is a list of strings that may have spaces (you didn't specify) and data just joins them with spaces and no terminating newline.  You probably want to send the row itself (for row in csvfile) and not wrap in a csv.reader
